# Get Change Summary in Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Microsoft Sync Framework for syncing server and client SQL server 2005 database. My requirement is to get summary of all changes and display it to the user before actually perform sync operation.

Does any one have idea how can we get changes in microsoft sync framework before actually synchronize them?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using sync framework verison 1 you can use a interface class between your sync agent and your remote provider.

When the data is recieved to the interfaceclass, as a `SyncSession` object, you can prewiev it and or modifie it before passing it throw to the agent.

```
public class SynchronizationInterface
{
    public SyncContext GetChanges(SyncGroupMetadata groupMetadata, SyncSession syncSession)
    {
        SyncContext syncContext;
        syncContext = syncServiceClient.GetChanges(groupMetadata,syncSession);
        //Inspect and or modify the syncContext that's received.
        return syncContext;
     }
     //Implement ApplyChanges, GetServerInfo, GetSchema in the same manner.
}
```